# How can I make my app visible to implicit intents to open a PDF file?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I want to create a simple app that can view PDF files.

To test that I have deleted the default PDF file viewer on the emulator and when I want to open a PDF file the emulator says `Can't open that file`.

How can I make my app visible to that implicit intent so it will be used/shown when I click that PDF file?
What `<intent-filter>` configuration do I need to add in my `manifest.xml`, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@see [javdromero's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66481394/10508928)

javdromero's approach worked for me after making a few tweaks.

#### 1. Specify the PDF mime type

The mime type for PDF files is `application/pdf` so we have to use that:

```
android:mimeType="application/pdf"
```

The `android:host` attribute can be ignored because we don't take anything from the web and don't have the `android:scheme` attribute specified. The same goes for the `android:pathPattern` attribute. See the `<data>` element's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element).

That leaves us with an error message `Missing URL` and the text is in red.

#### 2. Ignore the Missing URL error

The `Missing URL` error concerns the whole `<intent-filter>` element because we should specify the `android:scheme` attribute there.
But we don't use any schemes so we import the `tools` namespace and specify the `tools:ignore` attribute:

```
tools:ignore="AppLinkError"
```

That leaves us with following `<intent-filter>` element configuration:

```
<intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, you aren't specifying your sdk version but check it

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*.csv" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Tells me `Missing URL` error when I do it like this. I specified `mimeType="application/pdf"` and `pathPattern=".*.pdf"`.

Comment: You can supress the warning with <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">